# SPDY in Node.js https.request()

Tags: javascript, node.js, spdy

Does https.request() uses SPDY when it's supported on the server side? And if yes, is there a way to disable it?

Comment: this repository has the answers you need https://github.com/indutny/spdy-transport (if you just wanna use a library use this one  https://github.com/indutny/node-spdy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it uses 1.1 or 1.0. I think the most popular library would be [Fedor Indutny's](https://github.com/indutny/node-spdy). I thought this would also be starting point to land it in core, but currently I don't see any sign of it.